# Is this true for all functions F from X to Y?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let X and Y be sets, and let A and B be any subsets of X. Determine if the following property is true for all functions F from X to Y.
$$F(A\cap B) \subseteq F(A) \cap F(B)$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? did you try anything at all?

Comment: I'm having trouble conceptualizing the problem. I know that for x to be in $F(A /cap B)$ it would have to be in both A and B, and functions can have multiple inputs pointing to one output, so I guess it's possible that this works, but it seems like it shouldn't necessarily since an overlap in output is not really the same as an overlap in input.

Comment: You should add to the question what you said. It is always better to post a question with a part saying why you can't solve it, and what have you tried before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Spell out what it means for $x$ to be an element in $F(A\cap B)$. 
Further hint: $x\in F(A\cap B)$ means that there is some $y\in A\cap B$ such that $x=f(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

$F(A\cap B)\subseteq F(A)$ and $F(A\cap B)\subseteq F(B)$, so...